# Force 500 error in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm building my first app in laravel 5.4 and I did a custom 500 error view `(resource/error/500.blade.php)` and I was wondering if there is any way that I could force the error.

Obviously nobody would want to have this error, but I was just wondering how would it look if it occurs.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Add `abort(500)` snippet somewhere in the flow your testing to view the page.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

`App::abort(500);`

Optionally, you may provide a response:

`App::abort(500, 'What you want to message');`

Link to the docs [here](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/errors#http-exceptions)